# Azure maps Route Response To Windows.Services.Maps.MapControl

Tags: uwp, bing-maps

I noticed that with the Windows.Services.Maps.MapControl the :

```
MapRouteFinderResult result = await 
MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteFromWaypointsAsync(points, 
MapRouteOptimization.TimeWithTraffic);
```

It is not possible to get the shortest route AND have time with traffic enabled. I think? So I thought I would use the Azure Maps Routing Api which does give the options for both shortest route and trafic info. I was wondering if it is possible to render the results from Azure Api to the UWP MapControl?

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible since Azure Maps is a REST service, but legally there are some issues. The UWP control currently uses a different data provider from Azure Maps. UWP uses HERE currently and Azure Maps uses TomTom and mixing of the data is not allowed between the platforms.